# Using jQuery AJAX Postman Code Outside Postman is Failing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, api, postman

I can't figure out how to take a [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop) GET request and use it in actual code. I get the sense that I am missing something obvious, so any direction would be appreciated.

Here is the code:

```
var settings = {
  "async": true,
  "crossDomain": true,
  "url": "http://freshdesk.freshdesk.com/support/home",
  "method": "GET",
  "headers": {
    "cache-control": "no-cache",
    "postman-token": "abfd5ad4-315f-6a16-be62-20e92ec99baf"
  }
}

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

In Postman if you just add the url to the GET section and hit 'Send' it will return the HTML of the page. Here is a Codepen of the same code: [Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mBdwxB?editors=0011).

I have looked at some Postman documentation, and checked out some StackOverflow question/answers but haven't been able to find any good insight.

Thanks!

NOTE: Probably not that helpful of info, but Codepen in Chrome Canary on Mac was not giving ANY errors. When I checked in normal Chrome and Safari I got the errors one would expect.

Comment: What happens when you run the code? What problem are you seeing?

Comment: I assume you are running into CORS issues. Try googling around using that keyword. Essentially, you cannot make client (javascript) requests to a cross domain API without it letting you. A solution can be to send this request to your server and have your server send the request from there and return the results back to your client.

Comment: @AndrewLohr I don't recall seeing errors, but I think you're right, I'm seeing some issues in the console now. Checking those out (including the CORS)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to security policies (CORS) built in to the browser, which Postman doesn't have.

Your question was already asked and answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20035319/3990318).